# fetching list of friends using facebook 2.0

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

is there any way to fetch list of friends using facebook 2.0 API?
I was reading this [upgrade from the API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/) and it seems it is quite difficult to fetch the friends now,
but I have seen 2 permissions

- read_friendlist
- user_friends

Is their any way to fetch list of friends? and what about the widgets that get friends from facebook, will they go down?

Answer (score 3):

In v2.0 of the Graph API `/me/friends` returns the user's friends who also use the app. You need to be granted the user_friends permission in order to get even app-using friends.

There is no way in v2.0 to get the full user's friends.

However, you may use the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/invitable_friends API or the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends APIs to get all the user's friends with tokens than can be used for tagging and inviting.

the `read_friendlist` perm doesn't get you a list of the user's friends, it gets you the list of a user's friendlists which may be used to build a custom privacy selector when publishing stories to Facebook.

Comment: what about the apps that entirely depend on fetching the friends and then selecting one of the friend from or manupulating their info, will they go down?

Comment: ... yes, they will go down. No way to implement "Pay with Facebook" in mobile banking apps, for example.

Comment: I have opened issue on the Facebook Graph API - help by subscribing and opening related issues: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1502515636638396

Comment: Sign in petition for API change: https://www.change.org/petitions/facebook-platform-team-allow-developers-to-access-the-list-of-friends-from-users-of-their-apps?lang=en-US

Comment: It's really bad because my app allows users to send stuff to friends, but their friends can't possibly receive anything until they get my app too. Zero harassment. I just wanted a way for people to use my app before any of their friends use it. But now, I'm going to have to resort to the Message Dialog to invite people to my app; I hate apps that do that!

Answer (score 1):

As of 4/30/2014, you can only retrieve the friends who also use the app.

There are, however, specific methods for apps in the 'Game' category for inviting friends.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/invitable_friends/

Comment: that is just inviting, cant fetch all friends info i guess

Comment: You can't use it on mobile games until you have Canvas based web app. Seems Facebook just want to stick to web as they would not able to materialise their APIs on Mobile into gold farm.

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to about web-only, but I don't believe that is accurate.